# Ffmpeg not able to access file on aws labmda

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, lambda, ffmpeg

I am using ffmpeg to create video thumbnails on AWS Lambda. I downloaded the file in /tmp directory but ffmpeg is not able to access it and giving error

> [Error: meta data contains no duration, aborting screenshot creation]

when I am checking the media info using ffmpeg then it is giving the output

```
{ ffmpegversion: 0, title: '', artist: '', album: '', track: '', date: '', durationraw: '', durationsec: 0, synched: false, major_brand: undefined, video: { container: '', bitrate: 0, codec: '', resolution: { w: 0, h: 0 }, resolutionSquare: { w: 0, h: NaN }, rotate: 0, fps: 0, stream: 0, aspect: 0, pixel: 0 }, audio: { codec: '', bitrate: 0, sample_rate: 0, stream: 0 } }
```

I used `fs` module to check file existance on that location and it is giving the output

```
{ dev: 1793, mode: 33204, nlink: 1, uid: 496, gid: 495, rdev: 0, blksize: 4096, ino: 11, size: 21152, blocks: 48, atime: Thu Sep 01 2016 13:30:46 GMT+0000 (UTC), mtime: Thu Sep 01 2016 13:30:46 GMT+0000 (UTC), ctime: Thu Sep 01 2016 13:30:46 GMT+0000 (UTC), birthtime: Thu Sep 01 2016 13:30:46 GMT+0000 (UTC) }
```